# Why is my progress listener update callback not getting called in the OKHttp interceptor?

Tags: android, amazon-s3, okhttp

I've built a stripped down Android app to upload files to Amazon S3 using signed URLs. These URLs require a PUT call, which is slightly different than most file uploads which happen over POST.

I just paste in the S3 URL into the textview. I've verified the S3 URL works with this cURL command, so all is well with it.

`curl -X PUT 'https://mybucket.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/android/somevideo.mp4?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credentia...0&X-Amz-Signature=213123123&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host' --upload-file ~/Downloads/video.mp4`

The file upload completes correctly inside the Android app, but I never get into my `update` callback, so I cannot update the progress bar in the dialog.

Is there something different happening because I am doing a PUT request, and this is not a multipart form upload (I'm just sending the file as the body as an octet stream)?

My Activity code and the inner Progress class are all in one file below. When I set a breakpoint on line 126 (the `update` function), I never enter it. I used the [sample Progress listener linked here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/Progress.java), but for some reason my code never is called.

```
package com.example.putuploadwithprogress;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.Interceptor;
import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import okio.Buffer;
import okio.BufferedSource;
import okio.ForwardingSource;
import okio.Okio;
import okio.Source;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView uploadUrl = findViewById(R.id.uploadUrl);
    Button uploadButton = findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);

    uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        View layout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.upload_progress, null);
        final ProgressBar progress = layout.findViewById(R.id.uploadProgressBar);
        builder.setView(layout);
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
          }
        });
        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();

        final String url = uploadUrl.getText().toString().trim();

        try {
          new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              String mimeType = "video/mp4";
              String filename = Environment
                  .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment
                      .DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString() + "/video.mp4";
              File file = new File(filename);
              try {

                new Progress(url, file, mimeType, MainActivity.this, progress, dialog).run();
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                    dialog.hide();
                  }
                });

              } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println( "Got an error: " + e.getMessage());
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() { dialog.hide(); } });
              }
            }
          }).start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    });
  }
}

class Progress {

  private String mime;
  ProgressBar progressBar;
  AlertDialog dialog;
  Activity activity;
  private String url;
  private File file;

  Progress(String _url,
           File _file,
           String _mime,
           Activity _activity,
           ProgressBar _progressBar,
           AlertDialog _dialog) {
    url = _url;
    file = _file;
    mime = _mime;
    dialog = _dialog;
    progressBar = _progressBar;
    activity = _activity;
  }

  public void run()  {

    final Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .header("Content-Type", mime)
        .url(url)
        .put(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(mime), file))
        .build();

    final ProgressListener progressListener = new ProgressListener() {
      @Override
      public void update(long bytesRead, long contentLength, boolean done) {
        if (done) {
          if (dialog != null)
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                dialog.hide();
              }
            });
        } else {
          if (contentLength > 0) {
            final int progress = (int) (((double) bytesRead / contentLength) * 100);
            if (progressBar != null)
              activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                  progressBar.setProgress(progress);
                }
              });
          }
        }
      }
    };

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addNetworkInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
          @Override public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());
            return originalResponse.newBuilder()
                .body(new ProgressResponseBody(originalResponse.body(), progressListener))
                .build();
          }
        })
        .build();

    try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
      activity.runOnUiThread(
          new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
               if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                 String message = response.message();
                 Toast.makeText(activity, "Unable to upload file: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               } else {
                 Toast.makeText(activity, "Uploaded file successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
               dialog.hide();
             }
           });
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  interface ProgressListener {
    void update(long bytesRead, long contentLength, boolean done);
  }

  private static class ProgressResponseBody extends ResponseBody {

    private final ResponseBody responseBody;
    private final ProgressListener progressListener;
    private BufferedSource bufferedSource;

    ProgressResponseBody(ResponseBody responseBody, ProgressListener progressListener) {
      this.responseBody = responseBody;
      this.progressListener = progressListener;
    }

    @Override
    public MediaType contentType() {
      return responseBody.contentType();
    }

    @Override
    public long contentLength() {
      return responseBody.contentLength();
    }

    @Override
    public BufferedSource source() {
      if (bufferedSource == null) {
        bufferedSource = Okio.buffer(source(responseBody.source()));
      }
      return bufferedSource;
    }

    private Source source(Source source) {
      return new ForwardingSource(source) {
        long totalBytesRead = 0L;

        @Override
        public long read(Buffer sink, long byteCount) throws IOException {
          long bytesRead = super.read(sink, byteCount);
          // read() returns the number of bytes read, or -1 if this source is exhausted.
          totalBytesRead += bytesRead != -1 ? bytesRead : 0;
          progressListener.update(totalBytesRead, responseBody.contentLength(), bytesRead == -1);
          return bytesRead;
        }
      };
    }
  }

}
```

I've got two views. First, the `main_activity.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/uploadButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Upload File"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/uploadUrl"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="S3 URL, paste in here"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/uploadButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

`upload_progress.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/uploadProgressBar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:max="100"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        tools:progress="45" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="Uploading file..."
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/uploadProgressBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/uploadStatusMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="..."
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.SearchResult.Title"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/uploadProgressBar" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The Android manifest has the correct permissions for internet and I've enabled read permissions in the app permissions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.putuploadwithprogress">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Is function read(Buffer sink, long byteCount) being called for each byte read?

Comment: @NIKHILMAURYA no, I'm not seeing that hit either

Comment: I think you are tracking progress of the response body not the request body. try to use BufferedSink method try this https://gist.github.com/kyawkyaw/54d9e2feb1c969c90673

Answer (score 2):

The issue was, as [nikhil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5933012/nikhil-maurya) mentioned, that this was intercepting the response and not the request.

The interceptor needed to be changed this like:

```
.addNetworkInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
          @Override
          public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request originalRequest = chain.request();

            if (originalRequest.body() == null) {
              return chain.proceed(originalRequest);
            }
            Request progressRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                .method(originalRequest.method(),
                    new CountingRequestBody(originalRequest.body(), progressListener))
                .build();

            return chain.proceed(progressRequest);

          }
```

This below full code works.

```
package com.example.putuploadwithprogress;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.Interceptor;
import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;
import okio.Buffer;
import okio.BufferedSink;
import okio.ForwardingSink;
import okio.Okio;
import okio.Sink;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView uploadUrl = findViewById(R.id.uploadUrl);
    Button uploadButton = findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);

    uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        View layout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.upload_progress, null);
        final ProgressBar progress = layout.findViewById(R.id.uploadProgressBar);
        builder.setView(layout);
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
          }
        });
        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();

        final String url = uploadUrl.getText().toString().trim();

        try {
          new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              String mimeType = "video/mp4";
              String filename = Environment
                  .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment
                      .DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString() + "/video.mp4";
              File file = new File(filename);
              try {

                new Progress(url, file, mimeType, MainActivity.this, progress, dialog).run();
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                    dialog.hide();
                  }
                });

              } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println( "Got an error: " + e.getMessage());
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() { dialog.hide(); } });
              }
            }
          }).start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    });
  }
}

class Progress {

  private String mime;
  ProgressBar progressBar;
  AlertDialog dialog;
  Activity activity;
  private String url;
  private File file;

  Progress(String _url,
           File _file,
           String _mime,
           Activity _activity,
           ProgressBar _progressBar,
           AlertDialog _dialog) {
    url = _url;
    file = _file;
    mime = _mime;
    dialog = _dialog;
    progressBar = _progressBar;
    activity = _activity;
  }

  public void run() {

    final Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .header("Content-Type", mime)
        .url(url)
        .put(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(mime), file))
        .build();

    final CountingRequestBody.Listener progressListener = new CountingRequestBody.Listener() {
      @Override
      public void onRequestProgress(long bytesRead, long contentLength) {
        if (bytesRead >= contentLength) {
          if (dialog != null)
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                dialog.hide();
              }
            });
        } else {
          if (contentLength > 0) {
            final int progress = (int) (((double) bytesRead / contentLength) * 100);
            if (progressBar != null)
              activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                  progressBar.setProgress(progress);
                }
              });
          }
        }
      }
    };

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addNetworkInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
          @Override
          public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request originalRequest = chain.request();

            if (originalRequest.body() == null) {
              return chain.proceed(originalRequest);
            }
            Request progressRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                .method(originalRequest.method(),
                    new CountingRequestBody(originalRequest.body(), progressListener))
                .build();

            return chain.proceed(progressRequest);

          }
        })
        .build();

    try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
      activity.runOnUiThread(
          new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                String message = response.message();
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Unable to upload file: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              } else {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Uploaded file successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
              dialog.hide();
            }
          });
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}


class CountingRequestBody extends RequestBody {

  protected RequestBody delegate;
  protected Listener listener;

  protected CountingSink countingSink;

  public CountingRequestBody(RequestBody delegate, Listener listener) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
    this.listener = listener;
  }

  @Override public MediaType contentType() {
    return delegate.contentType();
  }

  @Override public long contentLength() {
    try {
      return delegate.contentLength();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return -1;
  }

  @Override public void writeTo(BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
    BufferedSink bufferedSink;

    countingSink = new CountingSink(sink);
    bufferedSink = Okio.buffer(countingSink);

    delegate.writeTo(bufferedSink);

    bufferedSink.flush();
  }

  protected final class CountingSink extends ForwardingSink {

    private long bytesWritten = 0;

    public CountingSink(Sink delegate) {
      super(delegate);
    }

    @Override public void write(Buffer source, long byteCount) throws IOException {
      super.write(source, byteCount);

      bytesWritten += byteCount;
      listener.onRequestProgress(bytesWritten, contentLength());
    }
  }

  public static interface Listener {

    public void onRequestProgress(long bytesWritten, long contentLength);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to force the `source` to buffer the entire body in my `ProgressResponseBody`:

```
 private fun createBufferedSource(): BufferedSource {
        return source(responseBody.source()).buffer().apply {
            request(Long.MAX_VALUE) // Buffer the entire body
        }
    }
```

Also you can do it from your `interceptor`:

```
class ProgressInterceptor(
    private val listener: DownloadProgressListener,
    private val filePath: String? = null,
) : Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Chain): Response {
        var response = chain.proceed(chain.request())

        response.body?.let { body ->
            response = response.newBuilder()
                .body(ProgressResponseBody(body, listener, filePath))
                .build()

            body.source().request(Long.MAX_VALUE) // Buffer the entire body
        }

        return response
    }
}
```